# unable to set GIT_WORK_TREE variable in a bare repository when using post_update hook

Tags: git

I am trying to set git up with http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website to manage my site. I am working using the git gui in win7

I have gotten to the last step in the instructions:  git push website

After pushing to the website, I was able to confirm that the object directory in  bare directory ~/website.git is updated.

my hook is called 'post_update' it has the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pushing data to Live Server.">>~/hi.txt
echo
export > ~.file1.txt
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/***/public_html/b1a
export >> ~.file1.txt
git checkout -f
```

when I go to /public_html/b1a, it is an empty directory. Please note, I have changed the hooks directory and b1a to 777.

I can confirm that the post_update hook is firing, because I printing the environmental variables to file1.txt (as you can see above). In the file I see:

```
GIT_DIR="."
```

but GIT_WORK_TREE is not seen. without the ability to set this I am stuck.

I would appreciate any help,

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: ok, so now I see your problem.

This is the script you need:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pushing data to Live Server.">>~/hi.txt
echo
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/***/public_html/b1a git checkout -f
```

I really don't know why nor how this works, but it does.

I don't know either why you were redirecting the `export` output to those files - do you really need that?

This script just check's out the current `HEAD` of the repository to the `GIT_WORK_TREE` directory. That's it. If you need anything else, please comment.

---

I think you're not exporting `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable.

Try changing those lines so you really export that variable instead of just setting it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pushing data to Live Server.">>~/hi.txt
echo
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/***/public_html/b1a
export > ~/.file1.txt
git checkout -f
```

The first `export` sets `GIT_WORK_TREE` value's and marks it for export, the second one outputs all current exported variables to the file.

I'm running this on Linux, but I hope it's the same on git-bash...

Comment: I have changed the file to look like yours. I am getting a remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree error now. entire output is                                                      remote: 
remote: 
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree[K
To ssh://****@****.net/home/***/website.git
   5450e91..5192e4f  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/website/master'

Comment: I did just look in file1.txt and now I have: export GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/***/public_html/b1a" included. so that should be correct. but the export is still not happening. Please note that ~/website.git is a bare repository as specified in the article

Comment: Hi So, I finally figured this out. the hook had been trying to send to the b1a directory which is NOT a git directory ( neither bare nor normal ). that explains the error. - Regards, Bill