# Checkout source files from local git repo to local folder

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, repository, git-checkout

I am using Amazon Ec2 . I am trying to create a Remote Repo on the Ec2 server to which I can check in code and run my server from there .

### Ec2 Server

Here is created two folders

```
/home/ubuntu/project.git <---- Repo
/home/ubuntu/project     <---- Source files to run server
```

I followed the instructions given here - http://blog.soarez.com/post/56644329478/deploy-a-node-js-service-on-ec2-with-git

Now from my local computer , I pushed the source files to project.git . It works fine . Files get pushed into the repo.

Now how do I get the files from the project.git to the project folder . 
I tried doing this , but it doesnt work -

```
cd ~/project.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/project git checkout -f
```

Comment: Do you have an error message or simply an empty `~/project` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd ~/project.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/project git checkout -f
```

This is the right way to checkout files from a [bare repo](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html).

But if the variable isn't see as exported by the git checkout command, you can wrap that in a script, like "[unable to set `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable in a bare repository when using `post_update` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554906/6309)" did.
That is what makes the a `post-receive` work, in the directory `~/project.git/hooks/`.