# Can not see changes using git push

Tags: git, github, push

I want to set up a　git environment for my PHP website. In my centos server, I created a directory and using `git init --bare --shared` to initial the git repository. Then I run `git add .` and `git commit`.

In my laptop, i use net beans IDE to get a clone of the git repository through SSH. I added some files and commit, push. It seems no problems.

My question is why I can not see any changes happened in my centos server. In the original repository, there are nothing changed. Do I need to run some commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **bare repo**, which means it has no working tree, no visible files.

See "[all about "bare" repos](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html)".

You would need to add a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to your bare repo in order to update a live site ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18804440/6309)).

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/your/site git checkout -f
```

See the full script in "[unable to set `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable in a bare repository when using `post_update` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554906/6309)".