# Problems with egit connecting to a git repository on a godaddy shared account

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

Our shared server account at godaddy comes preinstalled with git version 1.7.1. I've set up a bare repository following this strategy,

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

When I attempt to push via ssh in egit in eclipse I get this error,

> Can't connect to any URI: ssh://url:22/git-test/test.git 
>   (ssh://url:22/git-test/test.git: connection failed)

And yet using the same authentication in Putty I have no problem.

What I eventually want to do is to set up a git repository on the godaddy account that will permit development of the website from a few remote locations and then permit a push to production-live.

There is no git-daemon available, but apparently it isn't needed according to the above link.

This could be a problem with server configuration or remote setup on the egit side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are suing the full path of your repo

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://username@domain.com/home/username/path/git-test/test.git
```

(with [`test.git` being a **bare repo**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309), with a [post-receive hook to update the live site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19436394/6309))

Try it from the command line first (no need for putty), then [change your remote url on Eclipse/EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories).

You don't need to specify the port number (22 being the default one for ssh).

Comment: That was my problem, an incomplete path name. The name of my repo wasn't what I thought it was, so I got an error with git remote on the origin until I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was firewall by the VPN i used. By disabling the VPN Eclipse could push.