# Pre-push and post-push hooks involving remote checkout

Tags: git, githooks

I have a remote repository for a website which I am developing on my local machine.

I use `git flow` for neat branching model, so my branches are:

- master
- develop
- feature/one
- feature/two
- release/one
- release/two
- etc

The simplified work flow is as follows:

- make changes in `develop`
- push develop to backup server
- checkout to `master`
- merge `master` with develop`
- push `master` to live server

What I want to achieve, is that when I push `master` branch to live server, I should be able to instantly see changes when accessing website by URL.

The problem is that I can't really push `master`, because it is checked out on live server.

Can I write a pre-push hook which will do a checkout to `dummy` branch on remote, and a post-push hook which will do a checkout back to `master`? The point is that these hooks involves execution of git commands on remote and I'm not sure how to do this.

Would appreciate any examples very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push to master on a **[bare repo](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html)**.

Then a [`post-receive` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13554801/6309) can checkout that bare rpeo on your live server.

```
cd /path/to/bare/repo.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/live/server git checkout -f
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as a clock.