# Merging from local commits: up-to-date

Tags: git, git-merge

I have master repository at server and i have local clone from this.

I do at local:
change test.txt

```
git add test.txt
git commit -m 'test'
git push origin master
```

after this i dont see changes at test.txt. at git status i see

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   test.txt
```

i try

```
git merge _commitname
```

and see:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

UPD

```
git version 1.8.5.3 – at server
git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit – at client
```

diff:

```
--- test.txt 
+++ test.txt 
...[characters from test.txt]
```

Comment: What OS and what git version are you using? What `git branch` returns (do you see a '`*`' in front of master?)

Comment: [user@...]# git branch
  b145ecfc72ec5222e406578c0a280d9b01670944
* master

Comment: Ok. What does `git --version` returns? And do you see your changes when doing a `git diff HEAD~ HEAD -- test.txt`?

Comment: git version 1.8.5.3 – at server
git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit – at client

diff:
--- test.txt
+++ test.txt
...[characters from test.txt]

Comment: yes, i see my changes. in git diff, i mean

Comment: Do you see those changes on your Widows client? When you say "I dont see changes at `test.txt`", do you mean at your Debian server?

Comment: yes, i dont see changes at file on server, but see in git diff and in git log. in client i do changes and see it, of course.

Comment: But when you are pushing to the server, you are pushing to a bare repo, right? (a folder which ends with '`.git`': `myrepo.git`) So you wouldn't see *any* file in that repo.

Comment: okay, its very sad, but thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be seen on the destination, that is the server side.

The OP don't see the modification on the server side either because because:

- the destination repo is non-bare (in which case the working tree isn't updated)
- the destination repo is bare (in which case there is no file to see since it is a repo without working tree)
  That last case is usually completed by a **[post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20312097/6309)** in order to checkout that repo in a separate folder, in order to see what has just been pushed.

Answer (score 1):

It was non-bare repository with 1 branch (master)

i created new branch

```
git branch new
```

push commit from local repository

```
git push origin master:new
```

and do merge

```
git merge new
```

Comment: That can work indeed. +1. Pushing to a non-bare repo, to a branch which is *not* checked out is a legitimate push.