# Git: Why use a hook for setting up repo on your server?

Tags: git, version-control, web-hosting, githooks, bluehost

Tutorial after tutorial on setting up a git repo on your server are essentially all the same -- and they go like this:

1. Install git on your server
2. Create `git/project.git` off your root directory of your server
3. Initialize `git/project.git` using `git init --bare`
4. In `git/project.git/hooks` then `touch post-receive`
5. Add to post-receive: `#!/bin/bash\n 2 GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/your/vc'd/project git checkout -f`
6. Then make post-recieve executable: `chmod +x post-receive`
7. Back on your local machine, `git clone ssh://user@host.com/git/project.git`
8. And add files, commit and push

This is all fine, and I can indeed push to the `git/project.git` and end up with those files in the `path/to/your/vc'd/project` but I'm looking to understand...

***Why use the hook at all?***

It leaves you without the ability to pull your `path/to/your/vc'd/project/` on your local machine.
Why not just `git init` the `path/to/your/vc'd/project` and `clone` it on your local machine?

Further, if anyone could explain how to get `git pull` functionality on the local side for the `path/to/your/vc'd/project` with this hooking method, it would be much appreciated

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to push to a bare repo rather than a repo with a working tree.

That way, the user cannot be surprise to see the file pushed *not* be displayed, because the target repo would have one branch checked out and the user is pushing another branch.

Making the target repo update *automatically* a working tree based on what the user is pushing could be too dangerous: if you push the wrong branch, you replace your working tree content immediately.
This is different from pushing to a bare repo and [updating an external working tree through a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20312097/6309): you can do some control in said hook.

For more, see "[all about "bare" repos -- what, why, and how to fix a non-bare push](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html)".

Comment: The links are great. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like with git 1.7.0 or above you can simply `git init` your remote directory on the server and carry on normally.  Is that correct?

Comment: @patchwork on the server you would `git init --bare`, in order to make a repo to which you can push.